# Request for reference for some proofs about Gowers' norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, computational-complexity, additive-combinatorics, coding-theory, regularity

For any map $f : \mathbb{F}_2^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ we define its $d^{th}-$Gowers' Norm (for $1 \leq d \leq n$) as, $\|f\|_{U^d(\mathbb{F}_2^n)}^{2^d} = \mathbb{E}_{L : \mathbb{F}_2^d \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2^n} \Bigg [ \prod_{a \in \mathbb{F}^d_2} f(L(a)) \Bigg ]$ where $L$ are all affine maps between the said spaces. 
(..generally I don't see any need to specify the specific distribution being chosen to take the expectation over..)

There are $3$ properties of this norm that I want to see a proof of,

- It has a monotonicity property given as, 
  $0 \leq \|f\|_{U^1(\mathbb{F}_2^n)} \leq \|f\|_{U^2(\mathbb{F}_2^n)} \leq \cdots \leq \|f\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{F}_2^n)}$
- It apparently has a ``modulation symmetry" as,
  $\|fg\|_{U^d(\mathbb{F}_2^n)} = \|f\|_{U^d(\mathbb{F}_2^n)}$

where $g : \mathbb{F}_2^n \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2$ is any polynomial of degree at most $d-1$ in $n$ variables (i.e a ``Reed Muller code")

- $\|g\|_{U^d(\mathbb{F}_2^n)} = 1$ for any such $g$ as above.

Can someone link to a reference where these are proven?

(or if any of these have a short proof then can you type it in?)

Comment: *Gowers' (as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timothy_Gowers ; cf. "Stoke's theorem has to be a joke / Unless you thought his name was Stoke." —R.P.Boas)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! Sorry for not being careful!

Answer (score 1):

I think using the inductive definition of Gowers norms will be helpful...  This is in the corresponding chapter of Tao and Vu ("Additive combinatorics").

Comment: Yes. I have indeed tried that but I couldn't make the connection. The induction changes $f$ to another function which seems quite a new problem to solve! Its not an induction between the different Gowers' norm of the same function! What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In the polynomial property, you surely want $g$ to be the exponential of a polynomial. (Over $\mathbb F_2$, the relevant exponential function just takes $0$ to $1$ and $1$ to $-1$.)

For this property, and the third one, it's sufficient to check that $\prod_{a \in \mathbb F_2^d } g(L(a))=1$ for any exponential-of-polynomial $g$ of degree at most $d-1$ and linear map $L$, or that $\sum_{a \in \mathbb F_2^d} h(L(a))=0$ for any polynomial $h$ of degree at most $d-1$ and linear map $L$, or that $\sum_{a \in \mathbb F_2^d} h(a)=0$ for any polynomial $h$ of degree at most $d-1$ in $d$ variables, which you can prove by noting that, in each monomial, some variable must not appaear.

I think you want some complex conjugates in your definition of Gowers norm, although it won't affect the proofs of the last two properties, as you are working in $\mathbb F_2$. You will see the necessity in the Cauchy-Schwartz proof of the first property.

Comment: Thanks! I did worry about this point of which representation of $\mathbb{F}_2$ one is using. I see two things going around in the papers I have been looking at, (1) Those want to think of $\mathbb{F}_2$ as the $\{0,1\}$ set with multiplication and addition mod $2$ probably want $g$ to be defined as $(−1)^P$ where $P:\mathbb{F}_2^n \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2$ a degree $d−1$ polynomial. (2) Those who want $\mathbb{F}_2$ as the set $\{−1,1\}$ with multiplication and ``max" as the two operations probably want $g$ to be defined as I have done.

Comment: Is my understanding above correct?

Comment: @gradstuent That sounds right, although I've never heard the second class of functions described as polynomial.

Comment: So you think the modulation symmetry property and hence the Reed-Muller code being of unit Gowers norm property are true only in the first model where $\mathbb{F}_2 = \{0,1\}$ ?

Comment: BTW, it seems that you have thought of hyperplane arrangements before. So I thought I will draw your attention to this other question of mine, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272314/continuous-piecewise-linear-functions-which-induce-hyperplane-arrangements. Just incase you have some insights! :)

Comment: @gradstudent No, the two models are obviously equivalent, you just have to define the concepts in a different way for each one.

Comment: So what will have to change about the modularity and the unit norm properties of the Reed-Muller codes for the $\pm 1$ model of $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: I would love to see a reference where this property about $g$ and the modulation symmetry is proven. I cant find any!

Comment: @gradstudent You said it precisely - if you define a degree $d-1$ polynomial to be a product of terms, each a max of at most $d-1$ variables, then exactly the same argument by reduction to monomials works.

Answer (score 0):

The monotonicity property is a consequence of the Gowers Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. For the details, see (5.5)-(5.7) in Green-Tao: The primes contain arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions.

Comment: I think this "normalization" you talk of is related to the model of $\mathbb{F}_2$ that is being used. I have some confusion about this in my head. I have explained that in the comments to Will Sawin's answer. Could you kindly look at that and comment there?

Comment: @gradstudent: I see, your $g$ takes values in $\mathbb{F}_2$. Then you definitely need to adjust something as $f$ takes values in $\mathbb{C}$, so $fg$ makes no sense ($\mathbb{F}_2$ is not a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$). The second sentence in Will Sawin's comment makes a lot of sense, but I don't have time to look at this in detail.